# Expo Managed react native android application makes the request tothe nodejs on an EC2 instance, Building the application using EAS it is not working

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, amazon-ec2, expo

Expo Managed react native android application makes the request and receives the response to the the nodejs server on an EC2 instance on development server(using Expo start command on cli), But after Building the application using EAS cli and then the APK after installed in my phone or in my emulator is not making the requests ... Http protocol is used for the establishing the facilitating the req and response (and not HTTPS) . But when i used Ngrok for testing then the build worked fine , But it is not working when the server is in EC2 instance ?
Guide me how to solve the issue

Build apk must be able to make req and res to the EC2 instance server